# js/ jquery cant get dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im not very familiar with js and jquery and i have a problem with dynamically added elements.
Im programming a js mp3 player and I get a "m3u" kind of playlist from the server

```
#dir
#dir/artist
#dir/artist/album
dir/artist/album/song.mp3
// [...]
```

the js code inserts it in a ol:

```
<div data-id="container">
  <ol data-id="list">
    <li>dir</li>
    <li>artist</li>
    <li>album</li>
    <li><a href="https://localhost/[...]/dir/artist/album/song.mp3" id="title-1">song</a></li>
    <!-- [...] -->
  </ol>
</div>
```

---

this works:

```
$('[data-id=container]').on('click', '[data-id=list] li > a', function(e) {
  /*[...] */
}); // set audio src, ...
```

e.target is the  element i've clicked on

if i want to access it by its ID **in the js file** it returns undefined:

```
console.log($('#title-1'));
```

returns:

```
w.fn.init {}
  __proto__: Object(0)
```

if I type $('#title-1') in the chrome dev **console**, I get the object:

```
w.fn.init [a#title-1]
  0: a#title-1
  length: 1
  __proto__: Object(0)
```

---

Here is the code how i created the list:

```
function list(file) {
  $.get(file, function(list) {
    var list = list.split('\n'); //seperate file by lines
    var empty_line = 0;
    if (list[list.length - 1] == '') { empty_line = 1; } //ignore last line
    var j = 1; //counter for #title-n
    var text = ''; //output
    for (i = 0; i < (list.length - empty_line); i++) {
      var li = list[i].split('/');
      if (list[i][0] == '#') {
        text += tabs + '<li style="padding-left:' + (li.length - 1) * 10 + 'px;">' + li.pop().replace('#', '') + '</li>\n';
      } else {
        text += tabs + '<li style="padding-left:' + (li.length - 1) * 10 + 'px;"><a href="' + server_get_title + list[i] + '" id="title-' + j + '">' + li.pop() + '</a></li>\n';
        j++;
      }
    }
    $('[data-id=list]').html(text);
  }, 'text');
}
```

---

I've read something about adding elements "in the right way" so I tried

```
$('[data-id=list]').append($('<li><!-- [...] --></li>'));
```

or

```
obj[i] = $('<li><!-- [...] --></li>');
$('[data-id=list]').append(obj[i]);
```

and accessing the element by

```
obj[1].attr('href');
```

but with no success.

---

Any ideas how to solve it?

Thank you

### EDIT

my question is not about the "e" example, i want to access the element without clicking on it and getting e.target this way.

Comment: Where are you including the JS?

Comment: slava: <head>[...]<script src="player_client.js?v=0.21"></script></head> <br><br> david yes, of course, I forgot to add...

Comment: For jQuery reference to element clicked use `$(this)` inside event handler

Comment: e is going to return the event object. In your case the click event. If you want to get the element you clicked then you need to reference the this object.

Comment: andre, david, this isnt my question i just mentioned that i was able to access the element with e, the click event. e.target returns <a>...</a>. so i can access it with e.target.href, .id, ... My question is, how i can access the <a id="title-1> without clicking. so without an e.target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLUTION

this lines made all the trouble:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* ... */
  list('left-playlist-list', paths[1] + uri[1], 2);
  /* ... */
  console.log($('#title-1'));
  /* ... */
});
```

`console.log()` was fired **BEFORE** the list function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* ... */
  function first() {
    /* ... */
    list();
    /* ... */
  }
  function second() {
    /* ... */
    console.log($('#title-1'));
    /* ... */
  }
  // this is it
  $.ajax({
    url:first(), //call first()
    success:function(){ second(uri); } //and AFTER success call second()
  });
});
```

I came up with the idea that console.log() was fired to early during homework, so now they aren't pointless for me anymore ;D

Answer (score 0):

Some the `<ol>` is a static element in you HTML and it’s the `<li>` elements that are being created. You can write your code like this. This is another way to access the clicked element other that event target.

```
$('[data-id=list]').on('click', 'li > a', function(e) {
  console.log(this, ' element in vanilla JS. Or this wrapped in jQuery. ', $(this));
});
```

Comment: am i to stupid to explain my problem?... this is **not** my problem. my problem is that i can access the element (<a>) by chrome console but not in my JS file!